# How to set whole website as 2 column left in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, category, sidebar, column, sidemenu

I have installed magento2 and created the categories. I need to show all categories on left hand side vertically and all the content on right hand side?

Is that can be done? I am able to remove all categories from top navigation by below code.

```
 <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true" />
```

How i need to show all the categories vertically in left hand side? Please anyone suggest me.I couldn't find any appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to your backend -> Sales -> Categories -> Choose a Category -> Design

You can choose the design there, it might help.

[image]

Comment: hi, this makes only category pages not for all pages, and how the menus shown vertically if i do that configuration?

Comment: Then you should search for your theme, and in the design, there must be somewhere you can set the layout as this one. Which theme do you have?

Comment: I have created custom theme by setting luma as parent theme

Comment: Well, a custom theme where you have to define all this. Check how luma does this, and try to replicate.. I don't have the coding level to show you how to create that programatically from 0.

Comment: have you got my question? I need to show all categories vertically with 2 column left , but you are suggesting something different